# ASP.NET Core 2 SignalR Hub to receive complex object instead of string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm currently working on a ASP.NET Core 2 application using SignalR Core. I was wondering if it is possible to receive a complex object within the Hub class instead of a simple string or simple data structure.

Works - This example works fine: `string message`

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        // ... some logic
    }
}
```

Works - This example works fine as well: `List<Dictionary<string, object>> message`

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessage(List<Dictionary<string, object>> message)
    {
        // ... some logic
    }
}
```

Doesn't work correctly - It seems I cannot transfer complex objects via SignalR e.g. if I create a custom message class:

```
public class Message 
{
   public int MessageId { get; set; }

   public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Items { get; set; }

   public List<string> TextMessages { get; set; }
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessage(Message message)
    {
        // ... some logic
    }
}
```

Do you know how to transfer complex objects via a SignalR RPC?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the client side code as well for the hub where `SendMessage` accepts `Message` parameter? As long as you are sending in right JSON, it should go through.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working in .NET only, no JavaScript though... perhaps I'm just missing the [Serializable] attribute...

Comment: Share us your signalR client code.

Comment: I thought SignalR would automatically serialize your complex object into JSON for you, and then deserialize the JSON back to your complex object. I take it this is NOT correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow steps below for a working demo which passing `Message` between signalR Client and Server.

1. Server

   ```
   public class TimeHub: Hub
   {
       public async Task UpdateTime(string message)
       {
           if (Clients != null)
           {
               await Clients?.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
           }
       }
       public Task SendMessage(Message message)
       {
           // ... some logic
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Client

   ```
   private static async void Connect()
   {
       var hubConnectionBuilder = new HubConnectionBuilder();
       #region Worked
       var hubConnection = hubConnectionBuilder.WithUrl("https://localhost:44381/timeHub", options =>
       {

       }).Build();
       #endregion

       await hubConnection.StartAsync();
       await hubConnection.SendAsync("UpdateTime", $"From Client");
       var item1 = new Dictionary<string, object> {
           { "T1", new { Name = "TT1" } },
           { "T2", new { Name = "TT2" } },
           { "T3", new { Name = "TT3" } },
       };
       var item2 = new Dictionary<string, object> {
           { "T11", new { Name = "TT11" } },
           { "T12", new { Name = "TT12" } },
           { "T13", new { Name = "TT13" } },
       };

       await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", new Message {
           MessageId = 1,
           Items = new List<Dictionary<string, object>> {
               item1,
               item2
           },
           TextMessages = new List<string> {
               "H1",
               "H2"
           }
       });
       var on = hubConnection.On("ReceiveMessage", OnReceivedAction);
       Console.WriteLine($"Client is Start");
       Console.ReadLine();
       on.Dispose();
       await hubConnection.StopAsync();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget.

There you have a JsonConverter that can serializ your object.

So in your example:

```
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
          public Task SendMessage(Message message)
          {
             var messageJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Message>(message);
             // some logic
           }
    }
```

And on your client you can convert it back to an object. It´s have a nativ API so you just call

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage",  (message) => { 
    let messageObject = JSON.parse(message);
    // Other code here
});
```

Now message is again the object you send from the server.

And of course you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` to convert a json string you recieve from the client into a Object.

Comment: Excellent answer - going through the annoyance of how MS decided to handle serialize/deserialize  operations is aggravating. A nice simple - do it yourself solution like this helps alleviate headaches!

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering using JSON parsing just for the sake of passing multiple objects/parameters to client side, there is an alternative.

Server side (C#). You can pass any number of parameters to the anonymous object array.

```
SendCoreAsync("MethodName", new object[] {someObject, someNumber, someString });
```

Client side (Typescript)

```
private alertHandler = (someObject: any, someNumber: number, someString: string) => {
    console.log(someObject, someNumber, someString);
};
```

I have a slightly more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816782/249097)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was receiving a custom class on the hub method, but the properties of that class had no setters, so all properties were default values.

So each property needs `{ get; set; }` to be assigned during deserialization.